# TreeView WPF из различных объектов

Tags: c#, wpf

Как правильно в WPF организовать TreeView для различных объектов? Хотелось бы видеть подобную модель.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Классы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основная проблема в том, как сделать подобную привязку в WPF. Находила решения с использованием MuiltiBinding, но они не работают. Сейчас работает при указании в ресурсах TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate и DataTemplate, но он работает в случае, если в классе TreeObject есть свойство, возвращающее новый IEnumerable, в который добавляются все имеющиеся списки. Мне кажется это нецелесообразно по памяти, т.к. в классе уже есть списки нескольких объектов. Да и хочется попробовать как-то кастомизировать каждый отдельный тип объекта по-разному. Вопрос не имеет какой-то конкретной задачи, просто уже давно интересно и в долгих поисках, как же всё же это люди делают. Спасибо за отклики!

Comment: Такое делается путем создания интерфейса, некого обобщения, в котором строго будет прописана структура класс, дальше делается коллекция этого интерфейса, ну а в XAML через `DataTemplate` задается нужный вид для каждого типа по отдельности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покажу простейший пример работы с `TreeView`.

##### Структура классов

Первое что нам понадобится, так это продумать то, как в проекте будут взаимодействовать классы друг с другом, то есть нам надо грамотно спроектировать проект, определив все зависимости, повторяющиеся поведение и др. К примеру, вы можете сделать все на `object` или боже упаси на `dynamic`, ок, но будет ли дальше вам удобно с этим всем взаимодействовать? Думаю нет. Поэтому, давайте сделаем нечто удобное, базирующуюся на интерфейсах.

- И так, первым делом создадим интерфейс. Что от него требуется? Объединить в себе нечто общее классов и позволить нам хранить в той же коллекции несколько разных типов.

  ```
  public interface INode
  {
      public string Name { get; }
  }
  ```

  В данном примере, я вынес в интерфейс лишь название ноды, не более, ибо во всех классах оно должно быть.
- Далее создадим все необходимые нам типы:

  - Директория

    ```
    public class FolderNode : INode
    {
        public FolderNode(string name) => Name = name;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<INode> Items { get; set; }
    }
    ```
  - Изображение

    ```
    public class ImageNode : INode
    {
        public ImageNode(string name) => Name = name;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
    }
    ```
  - Музыка

    ```
    public class MusicNode: INode
    {
        public MusicNode(string name) => Name = name;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    }
    ```

  Как видите, это простые классы, с простыми свойствами и может даже своей логикой. Все зависит от того, что вы хотите и как.

##### Данные

Имея классы, мы можем теперь заполнять наши коллекции всем необходимым.

- Для удобства заполнения давайте сделаем самый простейший "билдер", чтоб немного упростить чтение кода.

  ```
  public class FolderBuilder
  {
      private FolderNode folder;
      public FolderBuilder(string name) => folder = new FolderNode(name);

      public FolderBuilder AddItem(INode node)
      {
          if (folder.Items is null)
              folder.Items = new List<INode>();

          folder.Items.Add(node);

          return this;
      }

      public FolderNode Build() => folder;
  }
  ```
- Ну и теперь, заполнение. Помним, что в WPF привязка доступна лишь к **публичным свойствам**. Также помним, что в случае, если коллекция уже была привязана и нам надо в ней изменить данные (добавить/удалить), то коллекция должна реализовывать `INotifyCollectionChanged`, из коробки в C# есть уже готовая для этого - `ObservableCollection<T>`.

  - Делаем свойство:

    ```
    public ObservableCollection<INode> Folders { get; set; } = new();
    ```
  - Заполняем:

    ```
    var concertFolder = new FolderBuilder("Записи с концерта")
        .AddItem(new MusicNode("Концерт №1") { Author = "Группа 1", Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(5), Size = 84496 })
        .AddItem(new MusicNode("Концерт №2") { Author = "Группа 1", Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(2), Size = 15347 })
        .Build();

    var musicFolder = new FolderBuilder("Музыка")
        .AddItem(new MusicNode("Трек #1") { Author = "Вася", Duration = new(0, 2, 37), Size = 5748 })
        .AddItem(new MusicNode("Трек #2") { Author = "Катя", Duration = new(0, 1, 52), Size = 1357 })
        .AddItem(new MusicNode("Трек #3") { Author = "Петр", Duration = new(0, 4, 43), Size = 4626 })
        .AddItem(new ImageNode("Обложка") { Format = "JPEG", Size = "1920x1080" })
        .AddItem(concertFolder)
        .Build();

    Folders.Add(musicFolder);
    ```

Тут как видите, простая коллекция, вам не мешает кто-либо добавить туда элементы циклом или еще каким-либо способом.

##### XAML (UI)

Теперь нам остается спроектировать интерфейс, прописав там все эти типы, указав то, как они должны отображаться. В WPF есть 2 предназначенных для этого элемента:

1. `DataTemplate` - позволяет указать тип (`DataType`) объекта и вид, который необходимо ему задать.
2. `HierarchicalDataTemplate` - аналогично простому `DataTemplate` за исключением того, что позволяет еще и задать `ItemsSource`, которую он будет отображать.

Зная это, давайте пропишем для всех наших типов соответствующий им вид:

- Директория (в себе содержит коллекцию, поэтому `HierarchicalDataTemplate`)

  ```
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FolderNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 3">
          <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18">
              <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                  <Path Fill="Black" Data="M6.1,10L4,18V8H21A2,2 0 0,0 19,6H12L10,4H4A2,2 0 0,0 2,6V18A2,2 0 0,0 4,20H19C19.9,20 20.7,19.4 20.9,18.5L23.2,10H6.1M19,18H6L7.6,12H20.6L19,18Z" />
              </Canvas>
          </Viewbox>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3 0 0 0" />
      </StackPanel>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  ```
- Изображение (достаточно простого `DataTemplate`)

  ```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ImageNode}">
      <Grid Margin="0 0 0 3">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18">
                  <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                      <Path Fill="#FF17BF9C" Data="M14,2L20,8V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6A2,2 0 0,1 4,20V4A2,2 0 0,1 6,2H14M18,20V9H13V4H6V20H18M17,13V19H7L12,14L14,16M10,10.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,1 8.5,12A1.5,1.5 0 0,1 7,10.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,1 8.5,9A1.5,1.5 0 0,1 10,10.5Z" />
                  </Canvas>
              </Viewbox>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3 0 0 0" />
          </StackPanel>
          <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Format}" Margin="0 0 3 0"/>
              <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Size}"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
  ```
- Музыка

  ```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MusicNode}">
      <Grid Margin="0 0 0 3">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18">
                  <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                      <Path Fill="#FFA4D81F" Data="M14,2L20,8V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6A2,2 0 0,1 4,20V4A2,2 0 0,1 6,2H14M18,20V9H13V4H6V20H18M13,10V12H11V17A2,2 0 0,1 9,19A2,2 0 0,1 7,17A2,2 0 0,1 9,15C9.4,15 9.7,15.1 10,15.3V10H13Z" />
                  </Canvas>
              </Viewbox>
              <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3 0 0 0" >
                  <Run Text="{Binding Author}"/>
                  <Run Text="-"/>
                  <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
              </TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
          <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Duration}" Margin="0 0 3 0"/>
              <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Size, StringFormat={}{0} кб}"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
  ```
- Теперь осталось сделать сам `TreeView` с указанием там `ItemsSource`

  ```
  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"/>
  ```

Все, вот мы и сделали отдельные классы, со своими данными, которые в UI отображаются по-разному. Как видите, сложного тут чего-либо нету, главное не запутаться) Естественно структура классов, вид и все остальное может быть совершенно разным, хоть на `object` постройте все, суть это не меняет. Главное, чтоб был объект (класс), ну и пояснить XAML как его обрабатывать, все. Кстати, этот "трюк" с `DataTemplate` работает везде, хоть выводите объект просто на экран, хоть в `ListBox`, хоть еще куда.

[image: Result]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как всегда выручаете! А DataTemplate можно свободно в разметке указать или в ресурсах элемента? В ресурсах ругается, если DataTemplate больше одного раза встречается.

Comment: @AB В ресурсах элемента, окна, приложения. Можете хоть отдельную библиотеку сделать со всеми ресурсами и вынести туда все это (только указать путь к словарю не забудьте). Когда писал этот пример, я лично разместил все в ресурсах окна `<Window.Resources> все DataTemplate </Window.Resources>`, также проверил сейчас в `App.xaml`, поместив все в `<Application.Resources>`. Учтите кстати, один тип = один `DataTemplate`.